# Is there any interface in Java with the readLine method like in BufferedReader class?

Tags: java, interface

I find it a bit odd that there is a number of `readLine` methods all over Java API, usually in stream or stream reader classes.

I would like to work with a kind of `Reader` that also supports line by line input reading (obviously implying a character reader).

I could specify the object as `BufferedReader` for one, but I would like to use an interface instead, to generalize it all a bit and allow other `readLine`-enabled `Reader` implementations.

I would suppose it would look something like the following:

```
interface LineReader
{
    String readLine();
}
```

I am guessing nothing like that exists in the "standard" Java API available as part of, say, Oracle Java 7 SDK? A bit of a mishap, is it not?

Comment: I don't know what is the question here. I appreciate that you shared your thoughts with us, but I think this is not the place to do so.

Comment: Hello Dariusz, I believe the question is very well presented in the title?

Comment: Yeah, but you know that BufferedReader does not implement that interface you are talking about. Therefore, even if there was such interface, it would be pointless in terms of *Reader usage.

Comment: No, I believe it wouldn't [be pointless], as the accepted answer below suggests. However, I still wanted to know whether such interface exists, so I wouldn't have to specify it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am guessing nothing like that exists in the "standard" Java API available as part of, say, Oracle Java 7 SDK?

Not that I know of. You can of course create your own interface:

```
interface LineReader {
    String readLine() throws IOException;
}

class BufferedLineReader extends BufferedReader implements LineReader {
   // ...
}

class SpecialLineReader implements LineReader {
    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
LineReader lr = new BufferedLineReader(new FileReader(...));
lr.readLine();

LineReader lr2 = new SpecialLineReader();
lr2.readLine();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. I think it's weird that the method is made available together with unrelated functionality (buffered reading) - this violates the principle of high cohesion and loose coupling in classes. Of course buffered reading eases implementation of line-by-line reading, but still...